# Different colors for different polylines on angular google maps using icons

Tags: typescript, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I have a requirement where based on the status of a routing leg, I need to have different colors for polylines, these polylines are not strokes but an icon. Currently I am able to plot the polylines with 1 color how can I plot them with multiple colors

here is my code so far for icon

```
public lineSymbol = {
    path: 'M 1,1, 1,1',
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokeColor : "black",
    scale: 4,
};
```

here is the code to plot polylines

```
private setMapPolylines() {
    if (this.pathValue != undefined && this.pathValue != null) this.pathValue.setMap(null);
    
    let pathArray = [];
    this.paths.forEach((path) => {
        pathArray.push({ lat: path.o.latitude, lng: path.o.longitude });
        pathArray.push({ lat: path.d.latitude, lng: path.d.longitude });
        switch(path.legStatus){
            
            case LegStatus.STARTED:
                this.lineSymbol.strokeColor = "black";
                
                break;
                case LegStatus.COMPLETED:
                this.lineSymbol.strokeColor = "green";
            
                break;
                case LegStatus.NOTSTARTED:
                this.lineSymbol.strokeColor = "gray";
                
                break;
        }
        console.log(this.lineSymbol.strokeColor);
        this.pathValue = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: pathArray,
            geodesic: false,
            strokeOpacity: 0,
            icons: [
                {
                    icon: this.lineSymbol,
                    offset: '0',
                    repeat: '20px',
                
                }
            ],
            
        });
        this.pathValue.setMap(this.map);
    });
}
```

this code plots everything as green, even when the data has some path which are started and should be black, the **console.log(this.lineSymbol.strokeColor)** shows the correct color.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Anguar but what `lineSymbol` is on `this`? From what I see, it used only inside the `forEach` callback. I'm not saying this is the reason, but it might. Also, if you can create a working codesanbox, I can try to debug it. If you want..

Comment: Could you also add how these icons are being created? Are they [Marker icons](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex?hl=en#maps_icon_complex-typescript)?

Answer (score 3):

It's because you are overwriting `this.lineSymbol.strokeColor` on every iteration of `paths`. If they need to be different, you define it per `path`:

```
private setMapPolylines() {
    if (this.pathValue != undefined && this.pathValue != null) this.pathValue.setMap(null);
    
    let pathArray = [];
    this.paths.forEach((path) => {
        pathArray.push({ lat: path.o.latitude, lng: path.o.longitude });
        pathArray.push({ lat: path.d.latitude, lng: path.d.longitude });
        let strokeColor = "black";
        switch(path.legStatus) {
            
            case LegStatus.COMPLETED:
                strokeColor = "green";
            
                break;
            case LegStatus.NOTSTARTED:
                strokeColor = "gray";
                
                break;
        }
        this.pathValue = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: pathArray,
            geodesic: false,
            strokeOpacity: 0,
            icons: [
                {
                    icon: {
                        strokeColor,
                        path: 'M 1,1, 1,1',
                        strokeOpacity: 1,                       
                        scale: 4,
                    },
                    offset: '0',
                    repeat: '20px',
                
                }
            ],
            
        });
        this.pathValue.setMap(this.map);
    });
}
```